# How to format yyyy-MMMM in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to format date column ("craeteddate") as yyyy-mmmm, i.e.: 2017-November.

```
select unix_timestamp(createddate, 'yyyy-MMMM') from cc_vw_case
```

This SQL throws "Bad date/time conversion format: yyyy-MMMM".
Is it possible format as yyyy-MMMM in Hive? I'm using Cloudera Hadoop.

Comment: Question can't be answered without knowing what `createddate` is

Answer (score 0):

If your input value is a Unix timestamp, then you'll need to use `FROM_UNIXTIME` instead of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. This gets the correct answer in Hive:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1510218382, 'yyyy-MMMM')
```

Answer: 2017-November

Comment: Right, if it's a timestamp, then you'll need to nest a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function inside, like: `FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(createdate), 'yyyy-MMMM')`.

Answer (score 0):

`unix_timestamp` is trying to parse your column, not format it.

Probably throws an error because it is not in the given format

You need to use a combination of `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col, "format from"), "format to")` to convert between datetimes